# Call a windows form dynamically by its title in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio, reference

I'm stuck with something that I have tried to overcome before and couldn't.
Last time I worked around it, but I really need to nail this down.

I have a multi-instance form which lists details of jobs, so a user may have 6 or so instances of this form open, all with different info. Lets call that form A.

Within form A there is an option to assign that job to a user.
Clicking that link label opens a new form using showdialog where a combobox is populated with logged in users... Lets call that form B.

What I want to do is have the value selected on form B passed back to form A, however because form A has multiple instances, I'm not sure how to call it.

Form A is JobDetails.vb, and always has a form title of "Job XXXXX Details", so I was hoping there was a way I could use the title to call it.

Hope that all make sense! Thanks in advance, and apologies if its a dumb question. I feel like this should be something obvious, but I just can't achieve it.

Comment: If you know what the form title is, you should be able to put the actual form on a separate variable and pass any data there.

Comment: The basic example on the [ShowDialog help page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx) does almost what you need. It gets a value from the dialog form when it closes and sets that on the main form.

Comment: So it does! ok... that example looks for 'system.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK' to say when you are done with the showdialog... is there a way I can look for a button pressed on the showdialog form instead?

Comment: Ahhh ok got it... just need to set the 'DialogResult' option on my 'assign' button and it works! Thanks - do you want to add that as an answer?

Comment: Glad it helped, I cooked up a crude example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown on the help page of [ShowDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx), you can easily alter the main form when the dialog-form is closed. So you could do something like this:

```
Public Sub ShowMyDialogBox()
    Dim testDialog As New Form2()

    ' Show testDialog as a modal dialog and determine if DialogResult = OK.
    If testDialog.ShowDialog(Me) = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

        Me.Text = String.Format("Jobs of {0}", testDialog.cmboUsers.SelectedValue)
    Else
        Me.Text = "Jobs"
    End If
    testDialog.Dispose()
End Sub
```